# How to update index in MongoDb when using Spring?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Let say I have class annotated with the following

```
@Data
@CompoundIndex(
    name = "unique_name_with_age",
    def = "{ 'firstName':1 , 'lastName':1 }",
    unique = true)
@Document
public class Person {
```

I believe the above means that the combination of `firstName` and `lastName` should always be unique.

Now what happens if I want to include another column in this constraints. Let say I now want

```
@Data
@CompoundIndex(
    name = "unique_name_with_age",
    def = "{ 'firstName':1 , 'lastName':1, 'ssn':1 }",
    unique = true)
@Document
public class Person {
```

so I want the `ssn` field to be considered in the unique constraints. My question is, how do I go about making this update?

In a typical RDBMS like postgres, I will need to run a command on the database that creates this unique constraints, and if need be, run a migration scripts to ensure already existing data does not violates this new constraints.

But I am not familair with MongoDB so not sure how to go about making these kinds of updates when using Spring data Mongodb annotations.

Comment: Spring data creates indexes if it not exists (it does not update it, your Spring data index definition and MongoDB should be compatible, otherwise, you will get `IndexKeySpecsConflict` ). You need to normalize your data manually and/or drop obsolete indexes and let Spring creates the index newly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Solution using Shell**

```
db.person.dropIndex('unique_name_with_age')

db.person.createIndex(
  {
      'firstName':1 , 'lastName':1, 'ssn':1 
  },
  {
      "name": "unique_name_with_age",
      "unique": true
  }
)
```

**Second Solution using Mongock**

This solution for migration uses [Mongock](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/get-started/index.html). A complexity in your case is that the index has the same name. Below I have explained the steps, but for clarity I have also created this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-spring-mongodb-update-index) which you can try out to see how Mongock operates. The  migration will require two steps:

1. Drop the existing index

This can be achieved by commenting out the existing `CompoundIndex` on your `Person` class and by creating a Mongock changeset to drop it.

```
@ChangeUnit(id = "person-updater-changeset", order = "1")
public class PersonUpdaterChange {
...
    @Execution
    public void changeSet() {
        //Drop the original index
        mongoTemplate.indexOps(Person.class).dropIndex("unique_name_with_age");
    }

    @RollbackExecution
    public void rollback() {
        // Provide a rollback here
    }
}
```

And run the application.

2. Updating the index on the person Entity

```
@CompoundIndex(
        name = "unique_name_with_age",
        def = "{ 'firstName':1 , 'lastName':1, 'ssn':1 }",
        unique = true)
```

And run the application.

Comment: I don't know Spring, but as far as I can tell this doesn't do what OP Is asking for. The question is about recreating the index with a different definition (adding a third field), but this answer seems to be demonstrating how to (re)save data. Can you clarify?

Comment: Resaving data using Mongock can help to update documents in MongoDB. However, in this particular case, there was an additional complexity, since the index has the same name and hibernate will not even allow the application to start (so the changeset/migration code can't be executed). So an additional step is needed. I updated the answer and provided an example repo that explains the different steps: https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-spring-mongodb-update-index

Comment: Thanks for this. But now I am wondering, is it not possible to update this from the cli? By running commands against the mongodb itself? Instead of running the whole application in other to update the indexes? if so how will that look like?

Comment: Surely, I assumed that you wanted migration in your application. I updated the answer.